# when I use textGeometry, spaces of the text are turned into question marks

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a 3D text created using textGeometry.

The problem is that the spaces in the letters are turned into question marks.

What can I do to solve this problem? This is my code.

```
    const loader = new FontLoader();
    const font = loader.parse(FontJSON);

    const textGeometry = new TextGeometry("abc de f", {
      font,
      size: 50,
      height: 10,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 3,
      bevelSize: 1,
      bevelOffset: 0,
      bevelSegments: 12,
    });

    const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
    textMesh.position.set(0, 0, -240);
    textMesh.geometry.center();

    init();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vf5x.png

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmpdbh62/1/. It's a simplified version of the official `webgl_geometry_text` demo. Do you mind updating the live example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @Mugen87 
I took the letters drawn on the canvas using the Vision API and made them in 3D form. Perhaps, if the character recognized by Vision API contains a space or enter, it appears as a question mark. This was a problem with the escape sequence and I solved the problem. Thanks for the nice example code!!